# Setting active class to current nav page

Tags: javascript

Im using jquery to set a active class to the current page. I was wondering whether this piece of code will work on larger websites with more complicated urls, or is there a simpler easier way of going about this.

```
//Active Menu
$(window).load(function(){

//Get and format current page from url.
var currentPage = window.location.pathname.split('/').reverse()[0];

//If needed, add exceptions to 'currentPage' value.
switch (currentPage){

}

//Target and loop through menu list.
$("#main-nav li a").each(function () {
    //if current page is equal to 'href' value of anchor tag. (Reason for the exceptions)
    if (currentPage === $(this).attr('href').split('/').reverse()[0]) {

        //Then add the active class to the closest li tag.
        $(this).closest('li').addClass('active');

    }
});

});
```

Comment: The phrase "larger websites with more complicated urls" makes this unanswerable. *Which* larger websites? What defines *more complicated urls*?

Comment: Why don't you do this server side? PHP...

Comment: I mean with websites when you start to pass data through the url i.e. ?data=value. Will this piece of code be able to handle this down the line. If not what is an easier way of going about this procedure.

Answer (score 0):

Just worked this out for myself thru much trial and error.

This worked for me :

```
$(document).context.all['li.id'].classList.add("classname");
$(document).context.all['li.id'].classList.remove("classname");
```